Some equivalent conditions for hyperbolicity of flow
Let  $M$  be  a  manifold and  $\phi_t$ be  a smooth flow associated to  a  smooth vector  field  on $M$.
Are the following  3 conditions  equivalent?
1)For  every  fixed $t$ the  diffeomorphism $\phi_t$ is  a  hyperbolic  diffeomorphism.(No  continuity  assumption on stable  and  unstable  distributions as  a grassman valued  map in $t$)
2)The  classical  definition of  hyperbolicityThe  splitting  of the  tangent  bundle to  stable and  unstable  subspace(The  splitting independent of  t)
3)The  condition  $2$ with  extra  assumption that stable and  unstable  distributions  are  invariant  under $D\phi_t$
